# google maps apiv3 - multiple dropdown categories/filter marker results

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to filter the marker result with two dropdown menus: 1). Select/show category One or Two. and 2). select/show only active or nonactive.  I got the active or nonactive to work but the first dropdown menu is not working with the other one.

```
<script>
(function() {
          var geocoder;

        var clusterer;

            window.onload = function() {

              // Creating a new map
              // Create a variable to make the map hover over Manchester upon initialising
    var map = new google.maps.LatLng(53.466808, -2.233936);
            var mapOptions = {
             center: map,
              zoom: 3,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    // end of the JSON script. If this could be referenced as an external resource that might be useful...
       }; 
       // the MapOptions variable is finished now
    // the map is defined below...
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions);

              //var selectDiv = $("#category_panel")[0];
              //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(selectDiv);


              var json = [
      {
        "title": "One",
        "lat": 58.9,
        "lng": 15.8,
        "description": "this is category Two and nonactive",
        "category" : [ "two" ],
        "status" : [ "nonactive" ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Two",
        "lat": 59.9,
        "lng": 10.8,
        "description": "This is in category One and is non-active",
        "category" : [ "one" ],
        "status" : [ "nonactive" ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Three",
        "lat": 55.7,
        "lng": 12.6,
        "description": "this is cateogory one and is active",
        "category" : [ "one" ],
        "status" : [ "active" ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Four",
        "lat": 59.9,
        "lng": 10.8,
        "description": "this is in category two is and active",
        "category" : [ "two" ],
        "status" : [ "active" ]
      }
    ];




              // Custom marker - Need one for each category
              var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png',
                new google.maps.Size(19, 25), // size of the image
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // origin, in this case top-left corner
              );

              // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
              var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

              // Marker Clusterer setup
              var mcOptions = {
                gridSize : 50,
                maxZoom : 15
              };
              clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

              var markers = {};
              var categoryIcons = {
                "one" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1%7CFF0000%7C000000",
                "two" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2%7C00FFFF%7C000000",
                "three" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=3%7CFF00FF%7C000000"
              }

              var statusIcons = {
                "active" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=10%7C00FFFF%7C000000",
                "nonactive" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=20%7C00FFFF%7C000000",

              }

              // Looping through the JSON data
              for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
                var data = json[i],
                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
                    category = data.category;
                    status = data.status;

                if (category in markers == false) {
                  markers[category] = [];
                }

                //adding Status the category

                 if (status in markers == false) {
                  markers[status] = [];
                }



                // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position : latLng,
                  title : data.title,
                  icon : categoryIcons[data.category],
                  icon: statusIcons[data.status]

                });
                markers[category].push(marker);

                 markers[status].push(marker);

                // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
                (function(marker, data) {

                  // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
                })(marker, data);

              }// END for loop

              $("#category").change(function(){
                var selected = $(this).val();
                clusterer.clearMarkers();
                clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
              });
              $("#category").change();



             $("#categoryAlt").change(function(){
                var selected = $(this).val();
                clusterer.clearMarkers();
                clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
              });
              $("#categoryAlt").change();





            }// END window.onload


          })();


          function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


     }
</script>
```

Here's my Html

```
<div id="category_panel">
    category:<select id="category">

      <option value="two">one</option>
      <option value="one">two</option>
      <!--<option value="three">three</option>-->

    </select>


    Status:<select id="categoryAlt">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
      <option value="active">Active</option>
      <option value="nonactive">Non-active</option>


    </select>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in dropdown list: values are inverted:

```
    Category:<select id="category">
        <option value="two">one</option>
        <option value="one">two</option>
        <!--<option value="three">three</option>-->
    </select>
```

They should be:

```
    Category:<select id="category">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <!--<option value="three">three</option>-->
    </select>
```

The following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

is triggered by selection of dropdown status `Nothing` by handler

```
$("#status").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    clusterer.clearMarkers();
    clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
});
$("#status").change();
```

markers['Nothing'] do not exist. So, I commented it out.

From json data we get markers array with 4 arrays of two elements. To filter it properly we have to change `category` and `status` change handlers and use also selection from the other dropdown list. Filtering is done based on title, better option would be on position (it requires some more work):

```
$("#category").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var statusSelected = $("#status").val();

    clusterer.clearMarkers();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers[selected].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < markers[statusSelected].length; j++) {
            if (markers[selected][i]['title'] == 
                markers[statusSelected][j]['title']) {
                clusterer.addMarkers([markers[selected][i]]);
            }
        }
    }
    // clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
});
$("#category").change();

$("#status").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var categorySelected = $("#category").val();

    clusterer.clearMarkers();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers[selected].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < markers[categorySelected].length; j++) {
            if (markers[selected][i]['title'] == 
                markers[categorySelected][j]['title']) {
                clusterer.addMarkers([markers[selected][i]]);
            }
        }
    }
    //clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
});
$("#status").change();
```

Changed code is in [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/veqe/1/edit). **Note:** it doesn't work there because there is no valid link for markerclusterer.js file.

BTW, I'd never design it like this. I'd build just one list of markers with information about status and category which can be filtered out in one pass.

**Update:** answer to @Freddie comment

I don't have anything written but it would be something like the following. `MarkerInfo` object contains information about created marker:

```
function MarkerInfo(marker, status, category) {
    this.marker = marker;
    this.status = status;
    this.category = category;
}
```

`markerList` array contains list of created `MarkerInfo`s (empty on init, at the end the length should be the same as number of markers):

```
var markerList = [];
```

How to fill it:

```
for/while reading from json
    read data for new marker (location, status, category...)
    create marker
    var markerInfo = new MarkerInfo(marker, status, category);
    markerList.push(markerInfo);
```

`$("#category").change(function() {...})` and `$("#status").change(function() {...})` could filter out marker with one loop.

Something like that.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't even think of it like that.  do you have an example (or link to one)? No worries if you don't, just interested to see it in action.

Comment: @Freddie: no link or example. I updated the answer with a kind of pseudocode to describe an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The select box for category seems to have mismatched display text and values.

These drop downs do nothing to filter each other. Either you are viewing all active/inactive or all one/two.

If you want to both select boxes filter the map, try something like this:

```
generateMarkers= function(category, status){
    return json.filter(function(item){
        return (!category || item.category.indexOf(category) !== -1) 
               && (!status || item.status.indexOf(status) !== -1);
    }).map(function(item){
        // generate your markers here
        return item.category+'_'+item.status;
    });
};
console.log(generateMarkers('two','nonactive'));

//clusterer.addMarkers(generateMarkers('two','nonactive'));
```

Comment: How does this work exactly? am I editing Json data loop?